# How to insert dynamic time on Outlook .ics file using PHP

Tags: outlook

I have this script that will let the user download the data from the database to .ics file using PHP. Now my problem is that I don't know how to modify dynamically the time of the outlook .ics file. My time format for example is 01:00 PM - 03:00 PM

I parse the time into 010000 and 030000, because the format of .ics file is HHMMSSZ "h" for hour "M" for minutes "S" for seconds and "Z" is for time zone.

Anyone can help?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", DueDate));
        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", startDate));
        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", endDate));
```